# Summary Report - Highlight matching values

Tags: reporting

I want to create a report which shows me whether two fields are matching

My matching pairs are:

```
Picklist Field 1: a, b, c, d, e
Record Type: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Matching rules:
a matches 1, 2
b, c matches 3
d, e matches 4, 5

My table looks like this:

Oppty Name , Field 1 , RecordType , Match?
Oppty 1, b , 4, FALSE
Oppty 2, c, 3, TRUE
Oppty 3, d, 3, FALSE
```

So, basically, in my report I want to create a formula field (Match?), where I highlight whether the values in the fields are a match against the record type, according to the matching rules I defined.
If I can do it using conditional highlighting that would be just as fine.

I created a formula field containing the first matching rule so far:

```
IF(
AND(
   RecordType.Name = "d",   
    OR(
      ISPICKVAL(Field1__c,"4"),
      ISPICKVAL(Field1__c,"5")
    )
  ),
1,0)
```

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.
The error message I get when I try to save this is:

```
Error: Invalid custom summary formula definition: Field RecordType.Name does not exist. Check spelling.
```

Any ideas?
Tia, Lily

Comment: you are creating standard reports or in VF apex code.

Comment: What is the Formula "data type" you chose?  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The datatype is Opportunity. All fields are on the opportunity. I am using standard reports. Basically what i want to do, if picklist 1 doesnt match picklist 2, I want to somehow highlight that in the report. Either in colour, or a formula field that shows a 1 or a 0.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce the error, but I was able to create a formula field that I believe does what you want:

```
IF(
    OR (
        AND(
            RecordType.Name = "a",   
            OR(
              ISPICKVAL(analysis__Field1__c,"1"),
              ISPICKVAL(analysis__Field1__c,"2")
            )
        ),
        AND(
            OR(
              RecordType.Name = "b", 
              RecordType.Name = "c"
            ),
            ISPICKVAL(analysis__Field1__c,"3")
        ),
        AND(
            OR(
              RecordType.Name = "d", 
              RecordType.Name = "e"
            ),
            OR(
              ISPICKVAL(analysis__Field1__c,"4"),
              ISPICKVAL(analysis__Field1__c,"5")
            )
        )
    )
    ,
    1
    ,
    0
)
```

Comment: She just need this part to return boolean: `OR (
        AND(
            RecordType.Name = "a",   
            OR(
              ISPICKVAL(analysis__Field1__c,"1"),
              ISPICKVAL(analysis__Field1__c,"2")
            )
        ),
        AND(
            ...
        ),
        AND(
            ...
        )
    )`

Answer (score 0):

Your formula field should be this

IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(Field_1__c,a),OR(ISPICKVAL(Field_2__c,1),ISPICKVAL(Field_2__c,2))),1,0)

Comment: Actually one of the picklists is not a picklist, but a record type. Is it possible to reference a record type in a formula field?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a dummy custom field to put the value of the record type (I do it using Apex Trigger). Then, use that field in your formula.